# try to create a PiChart at fragmet in Android but get a expection didn't find the class

Tags: android, xml, fragment

**Exception**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.kraassismentdashbordfragment/com.example.kraassismentdashbordf

I created a pie chart using activity in android but right now I try to create PiChart using fragment in android.

My app was crashed. but try to solve this problem. I got an exception: class is not found an exception

1.fragment_kraassismentdsgarboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context=".KRAassismentdsgarboardFragmentClass">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overal_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Overall Status"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.example.kraassismentdashboard.PiChart
                android:id="@+id/id_pichart"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:text="   0.83%" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/self_assisment_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Self-Assisment-Status"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

2. activity_main.xml

   ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/fragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:name="com.example.kraassismentdashbordfragment.KRAassismentdsgarboardFragmentClass"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragment_kraassismentdsgarboard" />
   ```
3. MainActivity.Java

```
      package com.example.kraassismentdashbordfragment;

      import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
      import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
      import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
      import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

      import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        //Fragment fragment =null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            KRAassismentdsgarboardFragmentClass kraFragment = new KRAassismentdsgarboardFragmentClass();
            loadFragment(kraFragment);



        }

        private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

4. KRAassismentdsgarboardFragmentClass

   ```
   public class KRAassismentdsgarboardFragmentClass extends Fragment {

       View view;


       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // Inflate the layout for this fragment

           view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kraassismentdsgarboard, container, false);

           int [] arr = {99,1};
           int [ ] color = {Color.GREEN,Color.YELLOW};

           PiChart piChart = view.findViewById(R.id.id_pichart);
           piChart.setData(arr,color);
           return view;
       }
   ```
5. PiChart

   ```
       public class PiChart extends View {

       private int[] mDataSet;
       private int[] mColorSet;
       private RectF mChart;
       private float mUnit;
       private float mStartAngle;
       private float mSweepAngle;
       private int mNotFillColor;

       public boolean isFill;

       private Paint paintArc;

       public PiChart(Context context) {
           super(context);
           init(context,  null);
       }

       public PiChart(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
           init(context, attrs);
       }

       private void init(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attributeSet){
           paintArc = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
           mChart = new RectF();
           mStartAngle = 0;
           isFill = true;
           mNotFillColor = Color.WHITE;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           super.onDraw(canvas);

           int H = getHeight();
           int W = getWidth();

           mChart.top = 0;
           mChart.left = 0;
           mChart.bottom = H;
           mChart.right = W;

           int totalData = mDataSet.length;
           for(int i = 0; i < totalData; i++){
               mSweepAngle = mUnit * mDataSet[i];
               paintArc.setColor(mColorSet[i]);
               canvas.drawArc(mChart, mStartAngle, mSweepAngle, true, paintArc);
               mStartAngle += mSweepAngle;
           }

           if(!isFill){
               Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
               paint.setColor(mNotFillColor);
               canvas.drawCircle(W / 2, H / 2, (int)((H / 2) - 70), paint);
           }
       }

       public void setData(int[] dataSet, int[] colorSet){
           this.mDataSet = dataSet;
           this.mColorSet = colorSet;

           initUnit(dataSet);
       }

       public void setNotFillColor(int color){
           mNotFillColor = color;
       }

       private void initUnit(int[] dataSet){
           int t = 0;

           for(int i: dataSet)
               t+=i;
           mUnit = 360.0f / t;
       }

       }
   ```

I would like to get answer a PiChart

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: yes, I added a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the package name is wrong on the xml for the PiChart . Try change this

```
<com.example.kraassismentdashboard.PiChart 
    android:id="@+id/id_pichart" 
    android:layout_width="300dp" 
    android:layout_height="300dp" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

To this.

```
<com.example.kraassismentdashbordfragment.PiChart 
    android:id="@+id/id_pichart" 
    android:layout_width="300dp" 
    android:layout_height="300dp" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your pie chart configuration code in **onViewCreated()** method of your fragment class. If you did not override this method of fragment do this and move your pie chart config code there. It's seems like your view is not present in view hierarchy when you trying to use it.

```
@override
void onViewCreated (View view,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    piChart.setData(arr,color);
}
```